# serializing issue with ASP.NET webservice ?

Tags: iphone, asp.net, objective-c, web-services

I need to run my iPhone application against a web service/API which was developed using asp.net.

For some reason the response which I get back from the API call adds extra characters and "d" in the beginning of the JSON as shown below.

```
{"d":"{\"count\":\"0\",\"status\":\"500\",\"recipes\":[]}"}
```

From my basic reading, this seems to be serializing issue on the service.

1. Am i wrong ??
2. Is there anyway I can deserilaize it to the right JSON on an iPhone client?

Help or guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

the whole think is a json which contains an object "D" with a string thats also json
so it is a json inside json.

so you have an 'outer json' : { "d" : "" }
+ an inner json : {"count":"0","status":"500","recipes":[]}

if we just inserted the inner json without \, we MIGHT get invalid json.. in practie (in this case) we wouldnt, but I assume the lib just tries to be on the safe side so it escapes the inner json and encodes it as a string!

getting the string and parsing it works fine as shown below and all is valid

```
id innerJSON = @"{\\\"count\\\":\\\"0\\\",\\\"status\\\":\\\"500\\\",\\\"recipes\\\":[]}";
id response = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"d\":\"%@\"}", innerJSON];
id data = [response dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
id outerJson = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@", outerJson[@"d"]);

data = [outerJson[@"d"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
id innerJson = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@ %@", innerJson[@"count"],innerJson[@"status"]);
```

Comment: sample added, the \\ are only needed for writing the string in the code. the actual string is 100% the one you have above

Comment: Yes. I understand that I can cruise through the data, in the way mentioned above, but is the response valid? I mean, why is there a "d" and "\" before every "

Comment: because the answer is a JSON string that contains another JSON string. the outerJSON == { "d" : "JSON_STRING" } if the inner JSON werent escaped, it would be invalid, that way it is VALID :)

Comment: ill edit my answer.. thought it was clear. ill try to reformulate it

Comment: OK. thanks for your answer now. But if this is the first step in my project, would you suggest me to issue a ticket on the server or continue working as it is. I am afraid that when the response becomes more complicated we might have further issues.

Comment: I would ask them, yes... it seems to be an unnecessary (AFAICS) redirection